# Intuition behind designing DNN models

Tags: neural-networks, references

For a long time, I have been looking for a reference that could give me an intuition for designing DNN models, however, I have met with little success. I have a set of training data, I know how input and output layers should look like, but what should I add in the middle?

Yes, everyone knows that RNNs are proper choice for time series, whereas Convolutions do a better job at vision. For NLP (or perhaps everything else) the go to is transformers. Add normalization for faster learning, to deal with overfit add dropout, etc, but these ideas are too broad and general. Although designing DNN models may not be very different from antique alchemy at the moment, I refuse to believe that researchers randomly put layers on top of each other until they get a good result, to publish it later on.

I am not looking for a set of rules that dictate how a DNN model should be designed, it doesn't exist yet, rather, I would like to get an intuition, a feeling that tells me for example, to add a pooling max layer, instead of a pooling average layer, after a convolution layer. Grid search and any other similar method is not really feasible. Sure it can be used for hyper parameters to some extent, but nothing beyond that really.

As a physicist, I have not gone through proper academic training for deep learning, so maybe that's why I am lacking this type of feeling, nevertheless, I appreciate any book, article, tutorial, etc, that can give me such intuition.

Comment: "I refuse to believe that researchers randomly put layers on top of each other until they get a good result, to publish it later on." I'm sorry for breaking the news for you, but it works absolutely like that. Obviously, researchers have operationalized such choices, but the design of deep neural networks is most often based on applying heuristics, starting from previous successful network architectures, and is quite handwavy. AutoML takes this to the extreme, performing meta-learning (i.e., optimizing the architecture to the task at hand).

Comment: @Firebug Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: @Dave I would call it more anecdotal than 'fact-based', including my own experience. I might delete it if a better-sourced answer appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry for breaking the news for you, but it works absolutely like that (this is mostly anecdotal based off my experience and what I see in the field, so I'm willing to delete this answer if someone brings up something else).

Obviously, researchers have operationalized such choices, but the design of deep neural networks is most often based on applying heuristics, starting from previous successful network architectures, and is quite handwavy.
AutoML takes this to the extreme, performing meta-learning (i.e., optimizing the architecture to the task at hand).

It's also possible to 'elicit' some choices based on group equivariances (i.e., convolutions give you translation equivariance).
This is an active area of research, although it does not answer the question of how many layers and how many units per layer are necessary.

Neural network architecture design is the topic of many books in the literature as well, you might want to check them.

---

Geometric deep learning can be a good gateway, providing an unification of most current neural network layers.
On this topic, you can find this book [Geometric Deep Learning: Grids, Groups, Graphs, Geodesics, and Gauges](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.13478)  and the accompanying portal https://geometricdeeplearning.com/, which contains a lot of material.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Can you please give me some references (or keywords) for finding papers regarding group equivalences? It does sound what I am looking for. Also suggesting some books helps.

Comment: @Paradoxy You can search for geometric deep learning, regarding the equivariances. Also, there is this book [Geometric Deep Learning: Grids, Groups, Graphs, Geodesics, and Gauges](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.13478) and this portal [https://geometricdeeplearning.com/](https://geometricdeeplearning.com/) with a lot of material.